# Why am I not getting a segfault error with this simple code?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

I have  to show an error when I access an item outside of an array (without creating my own function for it). So I just thought it was necessary to access the value out of the array to trigger a segfault but this code does not crash at all:

```
int main(){
    int tab[4];
    printf("%d", tab[7]);
}
```

Why I can't get an error when I'm doing this?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: If you are using GCC or Clang, try compiling and linking with `-fsanitize=address`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything can happen.  You program may crash, it may display strange results, or it may appear to work properly.

Also, making a seemingly unrelated change such as adding an unused local variable or a simple call to `printf` can change the way in which undefined behavior manifests itself.

When I ran this program, it completed and printed 63.  If I changed the referenced index from 7 to 7000, I get a segfault.

In short, just because the program *can* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Comment: Also, conversely, if a program does not (immediately) crash does not mean it is correct.

Comment: @RadLexus Right.  That falls under *it may appear to work correctly.*

Answer (score 2):

Because the behavior when you do things not allowed by the spec is ["undefined"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And because there are no bounds checks required in C. You got "lucky".

`int tab[4];` says to allocate memory for 4 integers on the stack. `tab` is just a number of a memory address. It doesn't know anything about what it's pointing at or how much space as been allocated.

`printf("%d", tab[7]);` says to print out the 8th element of `tab`. So the compiler does...

- `tab` is set to 1000 (for example) meaning memory address 1000.
- `tab` represents a list of `int`, so each element will be `sizeof(int)`, probably 4 or 8 bytes. Let's say 8.
- Therefore `tab[7]` means to start reading at memory position (7 * 8) + 1000 = 1056 and for 8 more bytes. So it reads 1056 to 1063.

That's it. No bounds checks by the program itself. The hardware or OS might do a bounds check to prevent one process from reading arbitrary memory, have a look into [protected memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection), but nothing required by C.

So `tab[7]` faithfully reproduces whatever garbage is in 1056 to 1063.

You can write a little program to see this.

```
int main(){
  int tab[4];
  printf("sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("tab: %d\n", tab);
  printf("&tab[7]: %d\n", &tab[7]);

  /* Note: tab must be cast to an integer else C will do pointer
     math on it. `7 + tab` gives the same result. */
  printf("(7 * sizeof(int)) + (int)tab: %d\n", (7 * sizeof(int)) + (int)tab);
  printf("7 + tab: %d\n", 7 + tab);
}
```

The exact results will vary, but you'll see that `&tab[7]` is just some math done on `tab` to figure out what memory address to examine.

```
$ ./test
sizeof(int): 4
tab: 1595446448
&tab[7]: 1595446476
(7 * sizeof(int)) + (int)tab: 1595446476
7 + tab: 1595446476
```

1595446476 - 1595446448 is 28. 7 * 4 is 28.

Answer (score 1):

An array in C is just a pointer to a block of memory with a starting point at, in this case, the arbitrary location of `tab[0]`. Sure you've set a bound of `4` but if you go past that, you just accessing random values that are past that block of memory. (i.e. the reason it is probably printing out weird numbers).